# How to strip/replace "domain\" from Pandas DataFrame Column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, strip

I have a pandas DataFrame that's being read in from a CSV that has hostnames of computers including the domain they belong to along with a bunch of other columns.  I'm trying to strip out the Domain information such that I'm left with ONLY the Hostname.

DataFrame ex:

```
name
domain1\computername1
domain1\computername45
dmain3\servername1
dmain3\computername3
domain1\servername64
....
```

I've tried using both str.strip() and str.replace() with a regex as well as a string literal, but I can't seem to correctly target the domain information correctly.

Examples of what I've tried thus far:

`df['name'].str.strip('.*\\')`

`df['name'].str.replace('.*\\', '', regex = True)`

`df['name'].str.replace(r'[.*\\]', '', regex = True)`

```
df['name'].str.replace('domain1\\\\', '', regex = False)
df['name'].str.replace('dmain3\\\\', '', regex = False)
```

None of these seem to make any changes when I spit the DataFrame out using `logging.debug(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already close to the answer, just use:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'.*\\', '', regex = True)
```

which just adds using r-string from one of your tried code.

Without using r-string here, the string is equivalent to `.*\\` which will be interpreted to only one `\` in the final regex.  However, with r-string, the string will becomes `'.*\\\\'` and each pair of `\\` will be interpreted finally as one `\` and final result becomes 2 slashes as you expect.

Output:

```
0     computername1
1    computername45
2       servername1
3     computername3
4      servername64
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: I just ran this in my code and it still did not remove the 'domain1\' as expected:

cbDF['name'].str.replace(r'.*\\','',regex = True)
logging.debug(cbDF)
logging.debug('completed.')
This still resulted in the domains being displayed in the debug log

Comment: @curtiplas  Just reassign it to `df['name']`..   See my edit above.

Comment: Gotcha - for some reason  I assumed that the str.replace behaved liked str.strip and did not require me to reassign the DataFrame column.

Comment: @curtiplas  Yes, this is a common pitfall to all of us.   Some other functions like `.rename()` also have the same kind of trap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.str.split`:

```
df["name"] = df["name"].str.split("\\", n=1).str[-1]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             name
0   computername1
1  computername45
2     servername1
3   computername3
4    servername64
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex approach with `ntpath.basename`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import ntpath
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':[r'domain1\computername1']})
df["name"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: ntpath.basename(x))
```

**Results**: `computername1`.

With `rsplit`:

```py
df["name"] = df["name"].str.rsplit('\\').str[-1]
```